# How can module be visible from one import and not visible from another?

Tags: python, python-import, pymysql

So I've got an application that's using `pymysql`, the pure python mysql client implementation. Before I go into my response, I'd like to stress the fact that I am not open to using a different mysql driver.

I have a module implementing a data structure that's backed by MySQL. The gist of the module is as follows:

```
import pymysql
class Whatever:
    def __init__(self):
        # Debug statement
        print dir(pymysql)
        # use the cursors submodule
        self.conn = pymysql.connect( ... , cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

When I import this in my test file, everything is fine. Here is the output of the `print` statement. In particular, I draw your attention to the cursors module:

```
['BINARY', 'Binary', 'Connect', 'Connection', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DBAPISet', 'DataError', 
'DatabaseError', 'Date', 'DateFromTicks', 'Error', 'FIELD_TYPE', 'IntegrityError', 
'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'MySQLError', 'NULL', 'NUMBER', 'NotSupportedError', 
'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'ROWID', 'STRING', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'Time', 
'TimeFromTicks', 'Timestamp', 'TimestampFromTicks', 'VERSION', 'Warning', '__all__', 
'__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 
'__version__', 'apilevel', 'charset', 'connect', 'connections', 'constants', 'converters', 
'cursors', 'err', 'escape_dict', 'escape_sequence', 'escape_string', 'get_client_info', 
'install_as_MySQLdb', 'paramstyle', 'sys', 'thread_safe', 'threadsafety', 'times', 'util', 
'version_info']
```

When I import the module from my main file, I get an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 72, in <module>
    passwd='', db='test_db')
  File "yyy.py", line 26, in __init__
    passwd=passwd, db=db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cursors'
```

The output of the `dir` print is as follows:

```
['BINARY', 'Binary', 'Connect', 'Connection', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DBAPISet', 
'DataError', 'DatabaseError', 'Date', 'DateFromTicks', 'Error', 'FIELD_TYPE', 
'IntegrityError', 'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'MySQLError', 'NULL', 'NUMBER', 
'NotSupportedError', 'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'ROWID', 'STRING', 'TIME', 
'TIMESTAMP', 'Time', 'TimeFromTicks', 'Timestamp', 'TimestampFromTicks', 'VERSION', 
'Warning', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__path__', '__version__', 'apilevel', 'charset', 'connect', 'constants', 'converters', 
'err', 'escape_dict', 'escape_sequence', 'escape_string', 'get_client_info', 
'install_as_MySQLdb', 'paramstyle', 'sys', 'thread_safe', 'threadsafety', 'times', 
'version_info']
```

Notably, `cursors` is absent. Checking `pymysql.__file__` is the same in both cases, and the output is:

```
__init__.py     charset.py  connections.py  constants   converters.pyc  cursors.pyc err.pyc     times.py    util.py
__init__.pyc    charset.pyc connections.pyc converters.py   cursors.py  err.py      tests       times.pyc   util.pyc
```

Clearly `cursors.py` is there. So what gives?

Comment: What's your code actually look like?  Could be a circular import issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an explicit `import pymysql.cursors` at the top of your file.

the `cursors` subpackage is not listed in the `pymysql`'s `__all__` and thus isn't imported when you do just `import pymysql`.

Comment: Yes it is, at least according to the latest on pymysql's github.  https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/__init__.py  Look at the bottom.

Comment: It indeed mentions it in `__all__` but it doesn't actually import the sub package into the namespace and is thus not actually exported as an attribute.

Comment: I can confirm that `import pymysql` doesn't automatically import `pymysql.cursors` for me.  I was writing up the same answer when I was beaten to the punch, so I upvoted this instead.

Comment: It does so indirectly, though not automatically, because the Connect function imports Connection from connections, which in turn imports Cursor from cursors.  Clearly, there's something else important that isn't being mentioned here.

Comment: @sr2222: ?  Are you saying that `import pymysql` and `import pymysql; pymysql.cursors` doesn't raise an `AttributeError` for you?

Comment: I tried explicitly doing `from pymysql import cursors`, and it works. Can anyone understand why?